# How can I control RC car?

Tags: control, raspberrypi, joystick, rasbperrypi, remote

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.
Please help me.
I'm sorry in poor English.

I want to remote control RC car by using PS3 joystick.
RC car by Raspberry Pi 2
PS3 joystick by PC

joystick:
rosrun joy joy_node

**Problem is a program for controlling RC car by using ROS is I do not know.**
but I can control RC car by using wiringPi.
Please teach me.

Raspberry Pi 2
ubuntu14.04 xubuntu
ROS indigo

PC
ubuntu 14.04 LTS
ROS indigo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220739/how-can-i-control-rc-car-?/) by [Kazuki Kadonaka](https://answers.ros.org/users/23157/kazuki-kadonaka/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2015-11-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think, it will be easier to connect an Arduino to your Raspberry pi. The arduino get the Information from the pi and will send it to the Servomotors.

The same like here:
http://answers.ros.org/question/194049/joy-to-control-servo/

There is also the code to send the Infos to your Arduino.
You need to install rosserial on your pi(including the arduino IDE, see tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial/Tutorials) and copy the code from the Servo-controller-example for your motors. You need to extend the code for your setup.

---

Originally posted by [rossi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4597/rossi/) with karma: 73 on 2016-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1